# Can I register/trigger my custom event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Lets say I would like to trigger a custom event, something like:

```
var foo = 5;

if(foo == 5){
    event(window,'fooIsFive');
}
```

and then

```
$(window).live('fooIsfive',function(){
    alert('hey! foo is five!');
});
```

(Please excuse my poor imagination right now.)

Is that possible? If not, is a similar approach possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, try this:

```
$(window).on('fooIsFive', function() { // on = jQ1.7, use bind for other versions
    alert('hey! foo is five!');
});

var foo = 5;
if (foo == 5) {
    $(window).trigger('fooIsFive');
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Mj62d/)**

Answer (score 0):

yes you can :

```
$(window).bind('eventName',function(e,a,b){
   console.log(a,b);
});
$(window).triggerHandler('eventName',['arg1','arg2']);
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/5TrH9/

Comment: bind is also depricated in jq1.7

Comment: I don't think that you need event delegation for custom events especially on the window, but heck, use all the `on` instead of `bind` you want... you will *clearly* see the improvements in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use backbone.js - http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Object events are at the at the core of backbone.js. you can take your Js app architecture to a whole new level with it.